# Access js function defined in global scope when css id's are shadowing them

Tags: javascript, css, browser, scope, frontend

Given this html document:

```
<script>
 const testfn = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(e);
 }
</script>
<form onsubmit='testfn(event)'>
    <input id='testfn'>
    <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

How do use the `testfn` event handler defined in the script tags?

(The in-scope `testfn` in the onsubmit handler is the input element because it has a matching id)

---

EDIT:

What's funny though is that this issue only occurs when it happens in a form and

1. the element with the id is an `input` element
2. the element with the attached event handler is also an `input`-ish element: an input, a button, or the onsubmit of the form

Given this is the way it is, perhaps for sports, **the better question is: is there any way to still access the javascript function from the onsubmit/click attribute of the input?**

Comment: Use a different name or use non-global scope. You can't make browsers not do that, despite it being a clearly awful idea.

Comment: @Pointy by non-global scope you mean access the function from "behind a dot" so to speak, i.e `mylib.testfn(event)`?

Comment: That's one possibility. If you use `.attachEventHandler()` or jQuery, you can bury your event handlers in immediately-invoked function expressions so that you use no global symbols at all. That's more flexible anyway.

Comment: @Pointy attachEventHandler?? You using RadEditor?

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for the feedback so far! I've updated the question to set it up more as of a challenge :). But I do understand that this is just the way it is, i.e not perfect :), and the best practice would be to avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to solving this.

## Don't use intrinsic event attributes

As you've discovered, they do *nasty* things to scope. Bind event handlers with JS instead.

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", testfn);
```

## Access the global via the `window` object

For this to work, the function first has to be attached to the window object. Declare it with `var` instead of `const`.

```
var testfn = etc;
```

Then you can access:

```
onsubmit="window.testfn(event)"
```

---

I'd recommend the former approach.

---

> What's funny though is that this issue only occurs when it happens in a form

This is due to a combination of factors. Intrinsic event attributes search properties of the event to which they are bound, and putting a control with an id in a form provides an accessor property to that element on the form matching the ID.

So `<form onsubmit='testfn(event)'>` ends up accessing `theForm.testfn` which is the input.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting that with a `var` it does actually get attached to `window` - thought that they are the same and didn't test with `var`.. I guess the main thing here is that when using an intrinsic event attribute there is a scope chain this call appears in, so things can shadow out the global thing?

Comment: But how do `var` and `const` differ in regard to scope - doesn't the function declaration appear in global scope anyway, and shouldn't it be reachable via `window` then by using either?

Comment: "I guess the main thing here is that when using an intrinsic event attribute there is a scope chain this call appears in, so things can shadow out the global thing?" — Yes.

Comment: "But how do var and const differ in regard to scope" — `var` is function level, `const` is block level. Only `var` will associate things with `window`